# $\int_D \left(\frac{1}{\Bigr((x+1)^2+(y+1)^2+(z+2)^2 \Bigr)^{10}} - \frac{1}{\Bigr(1^2+1^2+2^2 \Bigr)^{10}} \right) dS$ is positive or negative?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

Let $e_1=(1,0,2), e_2:=(0,1,0)$ be the  vector in $\mathbb R^3$.

We define $D:=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb {R}^3: x+2z=0; x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1 \}$. I would like to compute exactly the following integral:

$$
A:=\int_D \left(\frac{1}{\Bigr((x+1)^2+(y+1)^2+(z+2)^2 \Bigr)^{10}} - \frac{1}{\Bigr(1^2+1^2+2^2 \Bigr)^{10}} \right) dS
$$

Here $\int_D f dS$ means the surface integral of $S$ on defined surface domain $D$.

I want to know that $A$ is positive or negative

I am tried to change variable $(x,y)\mapsto (x,y,-x/2)$  or use the spherical coordinates. But the computation is very complicated because the function and the domain are not symmetric together!

Can you suggest me how to compute exactly the integral?

Comment: What makes you think you need to (or can) compute the integral exactly in order to estimate it? Also, saying volume of $D$ — rather than area of $D$ — may lead to confusion. Where did this come from?

Comment: The integral in the body of your post is different from the integral in the title.

Comment: Why did you define $e_1$ and $e_2$ if you’re not going to use them?

Comment: Roughly speaking, I would like to understand the integral over 2-dimensional ball B, this ball is perpendicular to a vector v, and the function is $|v+e+(x,y,z)|^{-10}$,  here$ |.|$ means the norm in $R^3$, e is a unit vector, v is a given vector

Comment: @MATH norm to the $10$th power would imply the integral in the post is incorrect. Which is the correct version?

Comment: @NinadMunshi thanks, i edited to the post

Comment: There are two different integrals, making the question incoherent.

Comment: *Can you suggest me how to compute exactly the integral?* *Mathematica* can evaluate it (it = the one in the body) exactly; it’s positive.

Comment: Your integral involves the norm to the *20th* power. Do you understand what [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm) means?

Comment: @Ghoster your right. The power can replace by any number $a$ but $a$ should not be chosen trivial :) I want to know how to solve the class of functions likes above

Comment: You might get more interest in this question if you explained what the significance of this integral is. Why are you interested in it? Also: It would be nice if you would **fix the title**.

Comment: If I were attempting to evaluate it by hand (which I am not), I would start by changing variables so that I was integrating over the unit disk in polar coordinates. Then I might try to do the angular integration using residues if it wasn’t otherwise clear how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider translating to a coordinate system centered at $(-1,-1,-2)$ and rotated such that the new $z$ unit vector is parallel to the old $(1,0,2)$ vector and $y$ remains unrotated. This gives us the new integral

$$I = \int_{D'}\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{10}}-\frac{1}{6^{10}}dS$$

where

$$D' = \{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb{R}^3:z = \sqrt{5}; x^2+(y-1)^2+(z-\sqrt{5})^2\leq 1\}$$

which simplifies the integral even further to

$$\int\limits_{x^2+(y-1)^2\leq 1}\frac{dA}{(x^2+y^2+5)^{10}}-\frac{\pi}{6^{10}}$$

The integral becomes

$$\int_0^\pi\int_0^{2\sin\theta}\frac{r\:dr\:d\theta}{(r^2+5)^{10}} = \frac{1}{18\cdot5^9}\int_0^\pi1-\frac{1}{(\frac{4}{5}\sin^2\theta+1)^9}\:d\theta$$

Using the substitution $t=\tan\theta$ we can get that integral evaluates to

$$\frac{1}{18\cdot5^9}\left(\pi - 2\int_0^\infty\frac{(t^2+1)^8dt}{\left(\frac{9}{5}t^2+1\right)^9}\right) = \frac{\pi}{18\cdot5^9}\left(1-\frac{1487675\sqrt{5}}{14348907}\right)$$

which is less than $\frac{\pi}{6^{10}}$, therefore $A$ is negative.